# Storing a URL on swipe

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cookies, local-storage

I am setting up a jQuery mobile project. It is the single page model and using swipe gestures to go to the next "page"

I am also wanting to save the URL that the user has swiped too in localStorage.

I have been pretty much successful with this, I have the code working, until I go back to the homepage then exit. If I try and go back, expecting to hit the homepage the browser just flickers and doesn't load anything!

It works perfectly on click, and when there is a hashurl (/#page2) but crashes when saving the root URL.

Code in head of doc:

```
if (localStorage.currentURL && location.currentURL != location.href) {
    location.href = localStorage.currentURL;
}
```

Then the script for saving the URL:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){          
    localStorage.currentURL = this.href
});

$(document).on('swipeleft', '.ui-page', function(event){    
    if(event.handled !== true) {    
        var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    localStorage.currentURL = window.location.href;
    return false;  
});

$(document).on('swiperight', '.ui-page', function(event){     
    if(event.handled !== true) {      
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    localStorage.currentURL = window.location.href;
    return false;      
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what error do you get in the console

Comment: No errors, as it seems to be stuck in some kind of loop, doesn't actually load the page, its like a constant redirect problem

Comment: I have also tried `localStorage.currentURL = location.href;`
With the same outcome